# Sencha Touch throwing appcache error when I open it on IE10+ browser

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have small application to display the data on city. It is working perfectly in Desktop  Chrome, Firefox, Safari browser . but I am getting AppCache error in IE10 and IE10+ browser

Answer (score 0):

To fix appcache issue you can follow below link.

https://umpiredeveloper.wordpress.com/2016/07/20/sencha-cache-appcache-file-loading-issue/